# How to avoid Golang server (Gin Gonic) to crash on INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: rest, go, error-handling, crash, go-gin

first of all : I'm new to Go, I come from years of java development.

I have developed a little REST API using Gin Gonic.
One of my endpoint occasionally (so I can't reproduce on demand) crashes during an HTTP Get to an external API I don't manage. The error displayed is something like :

> stream error: stream ID 4; INTERNAL_ERROR

An extract from the code crashing :

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", apiUrl, nil)
if err != nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
    return result, err
}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return result, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

This crashes my server and stops it.

I don't understand what's happening, I'm handling all the errors in the code, so it looks like an uncaught exception comparing to java, but I don't know how to catch that error and keep my server running (I don't care about avoid the error itself, I just want my server to keep going).

Comment: you need to update more about the main func and error message. Basically, you can use recover in go. For example, defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Recovered in f", r)
        }
    }(). Ref: https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

Comment: **Your** **own** **code** crashes the server! If you call log.Fatal your server is terminated immediately. Just don't do that. It is a bit like asking: "How to avoid the pain when It hit my thumb with a hammer?": Do not hit your thumb with a hammer. One more  good advice. Do not guess what a function does but literally _always_ read their **full** documentation, including the **whole** package documentation. Unlike e.g. Javadoc the godoc contains valuable and _needed_ information.

Comment: Oh my god I would have never guessed a log function to make an exit ... too much expecting behaviour , not enough reading doc as you said, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In `gin-gonic` you can use `gin.Recover()` middleware that helps your application to recover from panic.

You can use instantiation via `gin.New()` or via `gin.Default()` (it's already included)

```golang
handlers := gin.New()
handlers.Use(gin.Recovery())
```

Answer (score 5):

log.Fatal makes an exit (dumb me, thanks Volker)

Comment: if you will change to `log.Panic` and will use `gin.Recover`, its going to solve your problems.